# Braking with a 2002 chevy avalanche

Tags: brakes, chevrolet, avalanche

Not sure what's going on.  When you step on the brake the pedal itself shakes and makes a weird grinding noise... 3 mechanics couldn't figure it out, just said it's common in that vehicle. Any thoughts you have would be greatly appreciated!!

Comment: Have all the pads and discs been inspected both inner and outer sides? Sounds like one of the pads may be down to metal.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like false ABS activation. Pretty common on these vehicles. See [this post](http://ricksfreeautorepairadvice.com/abs-activates-at-low-speeds-gm-vehicles/) on false ABS on GM vehicles.